# How to programmatically add props to jsx component

Tags: reactjs

Given:

```
let component = [];
switch(foo) {
  case 'bar':
    component  = <TheBarComponent/>
    break;
  case 'baz':
    component  = <TheBazComponent/>
    break;
  case ...
}
// set component properties here.
```

Given that all components in the `switch` have the same props signature, how do I set them in one place rather than in-lining them all in each `case` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use that `<ComponentNameHere>` syntax with a name starting with a capital letter, it's shorthand for `React.createElement(ComponentNameHere);`, which creates a component *instance*. Instances should be treated as immutable, so you don't want to be modifying it afterwards.

See the [JSX In Depth](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#the-transform) page for full details.

Instead, remember that the "tag name" in JSX is just a regular javascript identifier, so you can set it dynamically, like this:

```
let Component;
switch(foo) {
    case 'bar':
        Component  = TheBarComponent
        break;
    case 'baz':
        Component  = TheBazComponent
        break;
    case ...
}

let myComponent = <Component prop="value" />
```